# how do i reverse individual (and specific) columns in a 2d array (RUBY)

Tags: ruby, sorting, multidimensional-array, transpose

**RUBY** the goal is to get the max value from each of the four zones and get their sum.

**UPDATE** I came up with a solution, I'm sorry about the mixup. It turned out that the matrix is a 2n x 2n matrix so it could have been greater or smaller than 4x4 in fact it.  The solution i wrote below worked on all of the test cases. [Here is a link to the problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/flipping-the-matrix/problem)

[image]

I tried doing matrix.transpose then I tried reversing the specific array, that didn't work for all edge cases.
**Here is the code for that**

```
def flippingMatrix(matrix)
    2.times do
        matrix = matrix.transpose
        matrix = matrix.map do |array|
            if (array[-1] == array.max) || (array[-2] == array.max)
                array.reverse
            else
                array
            end
        end    
    end
    return matrix[0][0] + matrix[0][1] + matrix[1][0] + matrix[1][1]
end
```

I gave up and tried the below, which in my mind works, it also works for most edge cases but not all.
But i'm getting an error (**undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)**)
keep in mind when I print the results or spot_1, spot_2, spot_3, or spot_4 I get the correct answer. does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

**Here is a matrix that FAILED**

```
[
[517, 37, 380, 3727], 
[3049, 1181, 2690, 1587], 
[3227, 3500, 2665, 383], 
[4041, 2013, 384, 965]
]
**expected output: 12,881 (this fails)**
**because 4041 + 2013 + 3227 + 3500 = 12,881**
```

**Here is a matrix that PASSED**

```
[
[112, 42, 83, 119],
[56, 125, 56, 49],
[15, 78, 101, 43],
[62, 98, 114, 108],
] 
**expected output: 414 (this passes)**
```

**Here is the code**

```
def flippingMatrix(matrix)
    # Write your code here 
    spot_1 = [matrix[0][0] , matrix[0][3] , matrix[3][0] , matrix[3][3]].max
    spot_2 = [matrix[0][1] , matrix[0][2] , matrix[3][1] , matrix[3][2]].max
    spot_3 = [matrix[1][0] , matrix[1][3] , matrix[2][0] , matrix[2][3]].max
    spot_4 = [matrix[1][1] , matrix[1][2] , matrix[2][1] , matrix[2][2]].max
    return (spot_1 + spot_2 + spot_3 + spot_4)
end
```

Comment: It looks like you have your "FAILED" and "PASSED" matrices reversed.  Your second matrix has no commas.

Comment: are you sure the fail and pass matrices are not flipped? Because the second one is missing the comas.

Comment: The missing commas then explain the no method error because you are trying to to use [] on nil.

Comment: _"I tried doing matrix.transpose then I tried reversing the specific array"_ – where's the corresponding code? The code you showed sums values, it doesn't transform the array at all. _"Here is a matrix that FAILED"_ – failed what? Please clarify what your are trying to do (expected output!), what you already did and which part is not working. Be specific.

Comment: Thank you all, I've gone ahead and edited the post. to add the old code I was mentioning, Also the commas were left out on the passed array by mistake, they were not the culprit. The expected output is to get the sum of the max number from each of the four zones (see picture)

Comment: here is the link to the problem for your reference: [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/flipping-the-matrix/problem)

Comment: Please state which programming language you are using in your question and describe in more detail whats going on here.

Comment: `4041 + 2013 + 3227 + 3500 == 12781`. Do you think the 1st matrix failed because you were expecting a result of 12881? In exactly what situations (combinations of code & data) are you getting the "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)" error?

Comment: thanks all i solved it, turned out, some of the edge cases were more/less than a 4 by 4 matrix

Comment: After having initially upvoted the question I have changed that to a downvote because you materially changed the question (from a 4x 4 matrix to a 2n x 2n matrix) after answers had been posted. That violates SO rules, for reasons that should be obvious: it renders those answers incorrect or, in some cases, even non-sensical. You should leave this question unchanged and ask a separate question about 2n x 2n matrices.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer your question and at the same time suggest two other ways to obtain the desired sum.

Suppose

```
arr = [
  [  1,   30,   40,   2],
  [300, 4000, 1000, 200],
  [400, 3000, 2000, 100],
  [  4,   10,   20,   3]
]
```

**First solution**

We see that the desired return value is `4444`. This corresponds to

```
A B B A
C D D C
C D D C
A B B A
```

First create three helper methods.

---

*Compute the largest value among the four inner elements*

```
def mx(arr)
  [arr[1][1], arr[1][2], arr[2][1], arr[2][2]].max
end
```

```
mx(arr)
  #=> 4000
```

This is the largest of the "D" values.

---

*Reverse the first two and last two rows*

```
def row_flip(arr)
  [arr[1], arr[0], arr[3], arr[2]]
end
```

```
row_flip(arr)
  #=> [[300, 4000, 1000, 200],
  #    [  1,   30,   40,   2],
  #    [  4,   10,   20,   3],
  #    [400, 3000, 2000, 100]]
```

This allows us to use the method `mx` to obtain the largest of the "B" values.

---

*Reverse the first two and last two columns*

```
def column_flip(arr)
  row_flip(arr.transpose).transpose
end
```

```
column_flip(arr)
  #= [[  30,   1,   2,   40],
  #   [4000, 300, 200, 1000],
  #   [3000, 400, 100, 2000],
  #   [  10,   4,   3,   20]]
```

This allows us to use the method `mx` to obtain the largest of the "C" values.

---

Lastly, the maximum of the "A" values can be computed as follows.

```
t =  row_flip(column_flip(arr))
  #=> [[4000, 300, 200, 1000],
  #    [  30,   1,   2,   40],
  #    [  10,   4,   3,   20],
  #    [3000, 400, 100, 2000]]
```

```
mx(column_flip(t))
  #=> 4
```

The sum of the maximum values may therefore be computed as follows.

```
def sum_max(arr)
  t = column_flip(arr) 
  mx(arr) + mx(row_flip(arr)) + mx(t) + mx(row_flip(t))
end
```

```
sum_max(arr)
  #=> 4444
```

**Second solution**

Another way is the following:

```
[0, 1].product([0, 1]).sum do |i, j|
  [arr[i][j], arr[i][-j-1], arr[-i-1][j], arr[-i-1][-j-1]].max
end
  #=> 4444
```

---

To see how this works let me break this into two statements add a `puts` statement. Note that, for each of the groups A, B, C and D, the block variables `i` and `j` are the row and column indices of the top-left element of the group.

```
top_left_indices = [0, 1].product([0, 1])
  #=> [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
top_left_indices.sum do |i, j|
  a = [arr[i][j], arr[i][-j-1], arr[-i-1][j], arr[-i-1][-j-1]]
  puts a
  a.max
end
  #=> 4444
```

The prints the following.

```
[1, 2, 4, 3]
[30, 40, 10, 20]
[300, 200, 400, 100]
[4000, 1000, 3000, 2000]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time, this did really inspire me to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

ahhh I came up with an answer that answers all edge cases. I originally saw something like this in Javascript and kind of turned it into Ruby. Apparently some of the hidden edge cases (that were hidden) weren't all 4 by 4 some were smaller and some larger, that was the cause of the nil error.

**Here is the solution:**

```
def flippingMatrix(matrix)
    total = []   
    (0...(matrix.length/2)).each do |idx1|
        (0...(matrix.length/2)).each do |idx2|
            total << [matrix[idx1][idx2], 
            matrix[(matrix.length - 1)-idx1][idx2], 
            matrix[idx1][(matrix.length - 1)-idx2], 
            matrix[(matrix.length - 1)-idx1][(matrix.length - 1)-idx2]].max
        end 
    end
    total.sum
end
```

Thank you all for your support! I hope this helps someone in the near future.

Comment: I would look at that again.  Although your OP didn't make mention of larger and smaller matrices, this answer does, and this answer will not work properly even on a simple 3x3 matrix.  In addition, your method definition contains an external variable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I fixed the external variable it was a typo I put matrix instead of m, it wasn’t actually an external variable. Furthermore, this did in fact pass all of the tests.

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood your initial question then.  Your picture makes it seem like you're dealing with zones a, b, c, and d but I see now that down in your comments you posted a link that seems to indicate you're working with QUADRANTS (each containing a-d).  Very confusing.  I think your question could use some further clarification.  I deleted my previous answer because it was designed for a different thing entirely although, coincidentally, in most of my test cases ended up with the same result.

Comment: Completely aside: from a ruby code review perspective this would get a thumbs down. A little constructive criticism: 1) use communicative variable names (not `l`, `sm`, etc.) 2) for loops are frowned upon use `(0...sm).each` instead.3) ruby always returns the last statement in a method so the return is superfluous.

Comment: @engineersmnky Thank you for the feedback, I'll update my code.

Comment: You can simplify be writing `total = 0` then `total += [matrix[idx1][idx2],...`. Perhaps you missed the "Second solution" in my answer, which is a variation on this approach that generalizes to 2n x 2n matrices in the obvious way.